# DRF - Dynamically adding fields - (first time works, then throwing error)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I want to modify a `serializer` such that it contains `FIELD_display` field for every field which has any choices, the value is `get_FIELD_display`.

I'm trying to dynamically add those fields inside `__init__` method and it works but then, after refresh it raises error:

```
Field name `ownership_display` is not valid for model `RealEstate`.
```

**serializer**

```
class ApiRealestateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = RealEstate
        fields = [x.name for x in RealEstate._meta.fields]

    def __init__(self, instance=None, data=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(instance, data, **kwargs)
        self.set_display_fields()


    def set_display_fields(self):
        """adds FIELD_display field for every CharField (eg. name = "peter", name_display = "Peter" )"""
        for field in RealEstate._meta.fields:
            if field.choices:
                fieldname = f"{field.name}_display"
                self.fields[fieldname] = serializers.CharField(source=f'get_{field.name}_display')
                self.Meta.fields.append(fieldname)
```

Do you know how to make it work?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is your end goal?

Comment: @GregSchmit To extend the API so when there is for example `subcategory` field in the model, you can see not only `subcategory` = "table_tenis", it automatically adds `subcategory_display` = "Table Tenis" to the serialized data.

Comment: Ah, gotcha, well I posted a half-answer then, more Traceback would be good to see where the error is being raised, and also maybe try putting the `set_display_fields` call before the `super().__init__` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I notice is that you're calling `super().__init__` **before** you set your display fields, so it's possible that the parent class method is throwing that error because when it is checking for the fields they don't exist yet, however you didn't post the full traceback and you didn't post enough for me to replicate.

It would be good to tell us exactly what you really want, because the pattern you're engaged in for that serializer looks... not good.